# Calculate time difference with formatted time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, mysqli

I have two times: a starting time and the duration. I want to subtract the duration from the starting time. The time I read from an mysql db and is already formatted. My code:

```
$start= $row["start"]; //output is for e.g. 08:00:00
$dur = $row["duration"]; //output is for e.g. 01:00:00

$sub = $start - $dur; 
// I want the output to be 07:00:00
// the result now is 7 and I got an error (non well formed numeric value)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: did you try to google it?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Comment: Yes, I already tried it. Always got this error:  DateInterval could not be converted to string.
I think this is because my time is already formatted in mysql db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can achieved like this

```
$date = "1970-01-01";
$start = $date." ".$row["start"];
$dur = $date ." ".$row["duration"];
$date1=date_create($start);
$date2=date_create($dur);
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%H:%I:%S");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$start= "08:00:00";
$dur = "01:00:00";

$diff = differenceInHours($start, $dur);

echo convertTime($diff);


function differenceInHours($startdate,$enddate){
    $starttimestamp = strtotime($startdate);
    $endtimestamp = strtotime($enddate);
    $difference = abs($endtimestamp - $starttimestamp)/3600;
    return $difference;
}

function convertTime($dec)
{
    // start by converting to seconds
    $seconds = ($dec * 3600);
    // we're given hours, so let's get those the easy way
    $hours = floor($dec);
    // since we've "calculated" hours, let's remove them from the seconds variable
    $seconds -= $hours * 3600;
    // calculate minutes left
    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
    // remove those from seconds as well
    $seconds -= $minutes * 60;
    // return the time formatted HH:MM:SS
    return lz($hours).":".lz($minutes).":".lz($seconds);
}

// lz = leading zero
function lz($num)
{
    return (strlen($num) < 2) ? "0{$num}" : $num;
}
```

Comment: Thanks yor your answer, but still the same error and the same output: 'A non well formed numeric value encountered' and output is for e.g. 7

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: My PHP version is 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You should always save date in your database in the appropriate format. And not as a "already formated" value. Except in very specific case.

Anyway, to solve your problem you can do soemthing like this

```
$start = new DateTime('08:00:00');
$duration = new DateTime('01:00:00');

$interval = date_diff($start, $duration);

echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S'); //ouput will be 07:00:00
```